# Migrate from spring cloud zuul api gateway to Amazon api gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I am currently trying to migrate my api gateway from spring cloud zuul to amazon api gateway, I have tried many articles but not able to do so.

Also on my api gateway currently authentication of jwt token is done also load balancing is there.

So after migrating to amazon api gateway do I need eureka discovery server or amazon api gateway will do that by self.

I am wondering how to achieve all this using amazon api gateway - service registration, load balancing, and configuring all of these?

Comment: What articles? Can you provide example of what you acheived so far?

Comment: Hi William Thanks for replying - So currently I have completed all the spring cloud stack using zuul, eureka. Now I have tried to deploy my microservices to EBS. But what I am finding diffcult is how to use AWS api gateway like zuul api gateway, how services will be registered, load balanced and that stuff I am doing with spring cloud stack can be done through AWS.